# Can't create table in database in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

In mySQL workbench, i can select my connected database:

```
SELECT "database-2.<>.rds.amazonaws.com";
```

but when i try to create a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyUsers ( firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

i get back:

```
Error Code 1046: No database selected
```

im not sure why, cause it seemed like in the first line i selected the aws database, which im already connected to in MySQL workbench.

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: You selected a server, you didn't select a database on the server.

Comment: yeah i selected the endpoint provided by rds. I thought this was the db name . . . where / how do i find my db name then?

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE mydbname;`

Comment: It might also be in the RDS dashboard.